# How multiple users of same department operates node via user interface which caters identity as "Bank node"?

Tags: corda

Will each user operates on Bank node's identity?

or

Will each user create separate identity as a "node" established as Bank user's node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Corda 3.1, each node can only have a single identity. We do not support multiple "user accounts" on the same node.

Instead, the bank node would have to perform actions on behalf of the bank's users.